# OpenSeaMap tiles over OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, openseamap

i already have an OSM server with north-america-latest.osm.pbf layer, this is rendered with mapnik.

My question is, where can I download OpenSeaMap layers and what would be the process for mounting on OSM layers that already have installed?

Would be the same process that do with the OSM layers?

Regards

Comment: I follow the next tutorial http://www.slideshare.net/MarcHuang1/build-your-ownmapbyyourself

Comment: or the openseamap layers only works online? i need do this in offline mode for an standalone server

Comment: Take a look at http://wiki.openseamap.org/wiki/OpenSeaMap-dev:Renderer or http://wiki.openseamap.org/wiki/OpenSeaMap-dev:De:Renderer to see how to render your own OpenSeaMap tiles (the German page seems to be more verbose).